# swift force viewController change from within webkit function

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I have a viewController showing a webkit view.

If the user browses to a certain type of link, then I want to move from that viewController to a new one, which can parse that specific type of url and display results (rather than moving to a new page)

However, as I understand it, in order to check the url links to see it's of the right kind then I need to use the function

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
```

but this only gives me the ability to write a bit of code to look at the URL link, and return a decision on whether to proceed to it or not, rather than what I want to do which is look at the URL link and then effectively segue to a completely new viewController to parse it.

Any ideas on how I should construct please?

Answer (score 0):

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Swift.Void)
    {
        if(navigationAction.navigationType == .other)
        {
            if navigationAction.request.url != nil
            {

           // Put your condition check on url.
// Create your view controller instance from storyboard. Pass the url to it and navigate. 
            }
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
```

Comment: The thing I'm struggling with is if I'm in webViewController A and call this function and create newController B from within the function then I'm creating B within A. If B wants to go to C then back to A then B again, this creates an ongoing stack of nested controllers. 
In a way what I'm after is a way to pass back the result of the 'decidePolicy' to the main body of webviewController A so that I can interpret result and segue / move to whatever viewController I want?